# Google not crawling my website

Tags: web-crawlers, googlebot, google-index

I own a website http://citrusbug.com. 
We did not have proper content before so to prevent search engine from crawling our site 
we added a *robots.txt* with code to prevent crawling.

Now we had updated our sites content and want to get it crawled, but Google is not crawling it yet. We removed the code from *robots.txt* to prevent Googlebot to crawl, but still it is not getting crawled.

We almost did this change before 20-21 days but still Google is not crawling our site and if search I search on Google it displays:

> A description for this result is not available because of this site's
>   robots.txt – learn more.

Kindly guide me, what I need to do for this?

Comment: Also many other questions and answers explaining why the site not be completely indexed, but Moobot answered well about `more time to crawl`. It's normal for sites to take ages to crawl, but do check obvious things like noindex, robots.txt (Again, tons of pages on here with this information).

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend signing up to Google's Webmaster Tools: https://www.google.com/webmasters/.

You can submit your site to Google there, check for crawl errors and get stats and details on how your site is performing in Google Search.

Answer (score 0):

Your site is being by crawled Google, you can see pages are getting indexed [here](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbo=d&site=&source=hp&q=site%3acitrusbug.com/&btnG=Search&pws=0&oq=%22broken%20and%20at%20worst%20the%20jaw%20can%20be%20broken%20and%20you%20can%20suffer%22&gs_l=hp.3...1327.2279.0.2529.3.3.0.0.0.0.202.475.0j2j1.3.0.les;ernk_rqr..0.0...1.1.2.hp.rCSBN_Q-gaU)

You may need to just give it a bit more time to crawl and re-index the enitre site.

I see you have a sitemap.xml file, have you submitted it in [Google Web Master Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)?  If not, do this, it could speed up the process.